# Pretty print json object in smarty

Tags: php, json, smarty

How can I pretty print into a div a json string assigned to smarty?

i know i can run php functions in smarty, so maybe a custom function will work?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to convert the object to an associative array, and then parse it. The function would look like this:

```
function format_json($array, $indent) {

    $indent_text = '';

    for ($ii = 0;$ii < $indent; $ii++)
        $indent_text .= '    ';

    echo '<br />'.$indent_text.'{<br />';

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo $indent_text.'"'.$key.'" : '; 
        if (is_array($value))
            format_json( $value, $indent + 1 );
        else echo '"'.$value.'"; <br />';
    }
    echo $indent_text.'}<br />';
}

<pre><code><?php format_json(json_decode($your_json_object, true), 0); ?></code></pre>
```

Obviously, you can style the  tag and change the indentation any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here is what I use which could be made into a function pretty easily, or just run inline:

```
<pre>
{$JSON_PRETTY_PRINT = 128}
{json_encode($some_json_object, $JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)}
</pre>
```

So in practice, it might look something like this.

```
{$data = json_decode('{}',1)}
{$data.some_string = 'abc'}
{$data.some_number = 1}
{$data.some_array = ["1","2","3"]}
{$data.some_obj = json_decode('{}',1)}
{$data.some_obj.foo = "bar"}}
{$data.some_array = ["1","2","3"]}
<pre>
{$JSON_PRETTY_PRINT = 128}
{json_encode($data, $JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)}
</pre>
```

Which would output:

```
{
    "some_string": "abc",
    "some_number": 1,
    "some_array": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ],
    "some_obj": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i am leaving here the function i wrote thanks to A.M.;

```
function smarty_function_pretty_format_json($params, $smarty)
{
  //$array // $indent

  $array = json_decode($params['json'], true);

 $indent_text = '';

    for ($ii = 0;$ii < $params['indent']; $ii++)
        $indent_text .= '    ';

    echo '<br />'.$indent_text.'{<br />';

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo $indent_text.'"'.$key.'" : '; 
        if (is_array($value))
            format_json( $value, $indent + 1 );
        else echo '"'.$value.'"; <br />';
    }
    echo $indent_text.'}<br />';
}
```

usage:

```
{pretty_format_json json=$json_object indent=0}
```